# radare2: how to pass parameters to debugee?

Tags: debugging, parameter-passing

I want to debug the program "id3v2 -c hallo test.mp3" with radare2.
How can I pass the arguments "-c hallo test.mp3" to radare2?

I only found something with rarun2, but when I do `r2 -d rarun2 program=/usr/bin/id3v2 arg1=-c arg2=hallo arg3=test.mp3`, the debugger is in rarun2 and not in id3v2.

Comment: this is a better question for [reverseengineering.se]

Answer (score 12):

You can pass arguments to radare2 debugged program in several ways.

The simplest way is:

```
r2 -d program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

- **r2** is an alias for radare2.
- **-d** is telling radare2 to debug the execuable.
- **arg1..3** are the arguments passed to the executable by radare2.

Another way is using the `ood` command inside radare2 shell:

Execute `radare2 ./program`, then type `ood arg1 arg2 arg3`. The `ood` command is used to "*reopen in debugger mode (with args)*".

You can also call `ood` with dynamic parameters using backticks. For example we want debug our program using the content from a file on our system as an arguments:

```
ood `!cat file.txt`
```

Say file.txt content is 'foo bar' so this equivalent to executing `ood foo bar`

- **backticks** are used for passing the output of radare2 commands.
- **!** is running the given command as in system(3).

Another way to pass arguments to radare2 debugged program is by using `rarun2` profile files:

```
$ r2 -R profile.rr2 -d program
$ cat profile.rr2
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
arg1=foo
arg2=bar
```

- **-R** [rarun2]  specify rarun2 profile to load.

Comment: I think is not longer '-R' but '-r' if you check the man files: "-r rarun2   Specify dbg.profile rarun2 profile to use when spawning a program for debugging" and "-R rarun2-directive: Specify custom rarun2 directives without having to create a rarun2 profile"

Comment: verified @Ricardo